# Query active directory to get a user's roles in .NET

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap

I have been using [Linq to Active Directory](http://linqtoad.codeplex.com/) a bit but I am finding it difficult to get a list of all roles of which the user is a member. I can retrieve a list of their immediate groups but it isn't recursive.

The reason I am trying to query AD directory is to work around the built-in Role Manager AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider which won't let you call Roles.GetRolesForUser(username) unless the username matches the current Windows Identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/active_directory_roles.aspx)?

Comment: The next answer by @marc_s gives you a simple method to see the Active Directory groups.   

This answer maps the AD groups to a read-only ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.RoleProvider that returns 'System.Web.Security.Role' objects, and the following methods:  
GetRolesForUser(username), GetUsersInRole(rolename), GetAllRoles(), IsUserInRole(user, role),  RoleExists(rolename)

Answer (score 20):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // find the roles....
   var roles = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

   // enumerate over them
   foreach (Principal p in roles)
   {
       // do something
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD:

Comment: I was testing this in a simple console app and figured out I needed to add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AcccountManagement` before I could get any of the code to work.