# Which one to use for Active Directory Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, security, active-directory, ldap, forms-authentication

I'm looking to switch to Active Directory for authentication and roles, but I'm not sure what to use for either.

For membership, I've come across these two options for authentication:

1. ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider
2. LdapMembershipProvider

What are the differences? Does one have an advantage over the other?
I just need to authenticate the user and know what roles they are in, nothing more.

For roles, I'm even less clear on what to use.

Thanks!

Comment: Will all of your users be on the network that they are accessing your site from? Is there a reason you want to use Forms Authentication instead of Integrated Windows Authentication?

Comment: They'll all be on the same network (company intranet)

Comment: Many systems can integrate with LDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate I find it simpler to just do something like this:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

bool flag = false;
try
{
    using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        flag = principalContext.ValidateCredentials("UserId", "Password");
    }
}
catch (PrincipalServerDownException)
{
}
```

To get roles you can look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247905/67566

I wouldn't use the two options you mentioned, personally, as there are newer options that I think make life simpler.

There are various options on instantiating PrincipleContext so you may want to look at:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there any web.config setup required? Does this code just go in the global.asax file?

Comment: Wow... I put the code in and it actually works. It just seemed too simple to work. Figured I would have to write subclasses and hookup things in the web.config.

Comment: MS has made authentication easier.  It used to be more work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to not use either membership provider you have suggested. Instead use Integrated Windows Authentication. You don't have to bother with logging users in and out as it's done via SPNEGO. Users just access the site and are automatically logged in (with some browsers, otherwise it prompts them for username/password and handles that for you). You can then figure out which user is logged in via the User.Identity.Name property available on any code behind page.

This is the simplest solution you'll find, as it doesn't take modification of any code or configuration files. Just check a simple box in IIS and you're good to go.

Comment: I guess it does make sense in a way. Then what is the point of ever using Active Directory for authentication?

Comment: Active Directory is handling your users logging into their accounts on their computers. When they authenticate, their credentials are verified against the credentials stored in your domain controllers. Integrated Windows Authentication uses the logged in user on the client and the trust between the web server and client as a means of determining who is accessing the site.

Comment: Integrated Auth works well for Chrome, Safari and IE, but for Firefox you would have to change the configuration on each machine to allow it to work, and that is only if people log in with their credentials on that computer.

Comment: @JamesBlack false. On Firefox it will prompt you for credentials similar to Basic authentication. So it does work. Or you can modify the Firefox configuration to pass the user through without the need to prompt for username and password.

Comment: I forgot you can enter the credentials, as when I encountered this the username the user knows is not the username in AD, so they were stuck.

Comment: @JamesBlack It is the same username used in AD. It is the full username, meaning the domain name is included. When you log into your Windows computer in an AD environment every day, you do specify a domain name, even though most people don't change it and just use the default.

Comment: I had to design a single-signon system for an application where the username wasn't what people logged in as, so it required doing some jumping through hoops.